# What does it mean to "spend pains upon someone"?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a [chapter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/levt104.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwir5qrY0JLiAhXGdn0KHXBwAkcQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw384-_Q7SNI1fdVJC9vVtDG) in my book which was:

> Sadao had taken this into his mind as he did everything his father said, his father who never joked or played with him but who spent infinite pains upon him who was his only son.

I don't know what spend means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more common today to speak of *spending time* on something - using your time for a particular purpose. *Pains* here means *trouble* - the father used up a great deal of effort trying to benefit his son, even though he didn't have fun with him.